# Handle with 'UIImagePickerController' and 'allowsEditing' to get perfect square

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I assure that UIImagePickerController always returns a squared image?
WhatsApp does it but I have not found a way to achieve this.

How it is in my App (Build in iOS 7)

[image]

How it should be (WhatsApp - iOS 6)

[image]

My code:

```
- (IBAction)showImagePicker:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    _imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You can alternatively use the ALAssetsLibrary (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to load your images which you can then also design custom interfaces rather than use Apple's UIImagePicker controller. Using a custom user interface, you can set a UIImageView's image aspect content fill mode.

Comment: Check out this question. Its similar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845949/set-minimum-zoom-level-for-uiimagepickercontroller-cropping

Answer (score 0):

well to change the size of the image captured you need to set the mode for view in your `UIImageView` in IB to scale to fill. then when the image is chosen from library or from camera, it automaticaly will be resized. you do have to turn the autolayout off though since it wont allow the `ImageView` to be resized. you code is fine. anyhow here is sample app codes you can build to understand it a bit better.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageTestViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)takePhoto:  (UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ImageTestController.h"

@interface ImageTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation ImageTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [myAlertView show];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

in the `ImageTestController` Xib or view in storyboard, place two buttons, one for each action and create the necessary links in IB. then place a `UIImageView` to fill whatever size you want in the view. click the `UIImageView` and in view section of attribute inspector change the mode to scale to fill. turn the autolayout off. try adding an image to your simulator just to test it. make sure the image is of the landscape size. build and run and when you select the image from image library, it will automatically resize to square or any other size you set your `UIImageView`.

i know you are aware of most of the steps above, but i wrote this answer not to just help you get rid of your issue but for others that may have similar issues. hope it helps you out man.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! But I am guess I expressed myself blurry. I added a sketch to my question to make it more clear.