# Zoom scale of crop view (UIImagePickerController) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to find a solution written in Swift to correct the zoom scale of crop view with landscape image. [GLImagePickerHelper](https://github.com/groovelab/GLImagePickerHelper) is what i need but is in objc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845949/set-minimum-zoom-level-for-uiimagepickercontroller-cropping) the proposed solution is also in objc. How can I do the same thing in Swift?